# When accessing my Windows DFS share on my Mac machine, it shows empty folder

Tags: network, windows, sharing, smb

I have a domain server mydomain.com and a DFS server which is part of mydomain.com. DFS server has a share with namespace `//mydomain.com/Datashare`, which points to a `TestData` folder inside the machine. `TestData` has a few files `1.txt`, `2.txt`.
When I access my DFS share on a Windows machine it mounts the share and shows the folder `TestData` with files `1.txt` and `2.txt`.
When I access the same share on my Mac machine it mounts the share and displays the `TestData` folder. however, it does not show any files inside this folder.

Someone discussed a solution of setting the same search domain on a Mac machine as AD sets on Windows but that solution does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Mac AD domain join does not add any search domain that might be needed to access domain services. after adding search domain for AD Domain, system was able to show files inside DFS shared folders.